# Event Log Service Failed to start - Error 2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Yesterday I rebooted my VMWare Virtual Machine Wndows Server 2008 unfortunately with the power off button...
This morning the Windows Event Log service doesn't start with the message:
"Windows could not start the Windows Event Log service on ... " Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.

Any Idea?
Thanks

Comment: Please add the detailed information of the Windows Event Log.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the values under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog

Answer (score 0):

A few things could have gone wrong from the viewer's setting becoming corrupt in some way to permission problems.  With the lack of detail, I shall take a bit of a guess.

To check to make sure the service is actually configured to start-up properly; go to your services to ensure that service `eventlog` (Windows Event Log) is set to `Automatic` start-up type and that it is configured with the proper account.  You might also need to tweak the recovery options.

To make sure the permissions are set properly for the service, go to `%windir%\system32\winevt\Logs` and ensure the proper permissions are set for the account that is running the `eventlog` service so that the process is actually able to use the directory.